# when click on "Submit" Button it should redirect to home page in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, html

when click on "Submit"  Button it should redirect to home page but in my code it is redirect to index page

This is my HTML code

```
<html xmlns:border="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
     <tr border:=" 1px solid black;">
            <td >
                User Name</td>

        </tr>
        <tr border:=" 1px solid black;">
            <td >
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr border:=" 1px solid black;">
            <td >
                Password</td>

        </tr>
        <tr border:=" 1px solid black;">
            <td  >
                <input type="text" name="password" id="password">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <button  onclick="test();">Submit</button>
            <td>
        </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my js code where I have defined the function

```
function test (){
   
alert("Shubham");
console.log("Shubham");
  $("#zzz").load("file:///android_asset/home.html");
   $("#zzz").hide();
}
```

This is my Java Code in android studio

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String rex="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            WebView webview;
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the Intent for Home Page Activity.